# fuser -v /dev/nvidia* and lsof not responding

Tags: nvidia, devices, gpu, lsof, fuser

On our A100 machine, we frequently have zombie processes that still allocate memory when already stopped. I usually used `fuser -v /dev/nvidia*` to determine the PIDs of all processes and kill them either with `kill` or `fuser -k /dev/nvidia*`.

`fuser` always took a short while to return the result. But now, the command `fuser -v` and `fuser -k` are hanging indefinitely, not responding within any reasonable amount of time. For example, last time, it ran a weekend without returning. I ended up restarting the server.

`fuser -v /dev/nvidia0` shows the same abnormal behavior, as does `lsof /dev/nvidia0`. When looking online for this issue, I only get answers to the zombie process problem mentioned above, but no problems specifically for the case when `fuser` or `lsof` are hanging.

How to debug/solve this problem ideally without restarting the machine?

The system runs Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Seek support from NVIDIA directly. This looks like an issue with their driver.

Comment: If you have excessive zombie processes, it may be that your diagnostic processes cannot start something they need, and also cannot report that fact. I would cron a script that measured the total number of processes and of zombies every 10 minutes, and rang some bells somewhere, or at least made a log you could analyse after a restart. You could also use cron to cull the zombies directly.

Comment: After a restart, `fuser` and `lsof` are quick again. Really strange this issue.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Zombie processes are appearing once every few days/weeks and then accumulate over some time. It's a regularly occurring problem and apparently, these zombie processes aren't that uncommon. Strangely, only our A100 servers are affected, not the V100 servers.

Comment: @Green绿色  You have it easy. My client was monitoring 160 servers with a product called BMC Patrol, which uses multiple agents. When that randomly stopped culling child processes, it would snowball up to process limit in about 30 minutes on multiple servers. Being as this was the live power control system for National Grid, this was a Bad Thing, so I was monitoring their own monitoring process 24/7 at 5-minute intervals.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Server administration is actually only my side-quest at work. These servers are only for local testing and development, so not much depends on it, but it's still annoying when we have to restart. Logging processes on the GPU might be a sensible thing to do, maybe we'd then find out what is causing these zombies. However, I'm still curious as to why `fuser` and `lsof` are hanging.

Comment: @Green绿色  Resource starvation. Fuser and Lsof have to search around for their results: the information they need is widely scattered. If you have a few hundred useless processes around (with memory, file descriptors, etc), the searches and the results will grow in size exponentially.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you!